# Problems casting dtypes

Tags: pandas, jupyter

i have a df lke this:

```
value_1  Value_2
 10.0     20.0
```

`value_1` and `value_2` as `float64`.

How do i cast it to int ad get this:

```
value_1  Value_2
  10     20
```

I tried:

```
   df.astype('int32').dtypes
```

didn´t work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `astype()` is not updating in place, remember to reassign to `df` after applying `astype()`:

```
df = df.astype('int32')
```

or simply:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

Note: The example shown on [official doc of astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) quoting:

> Cast all columns to int32:
> **df.astype('int32').dtypes**

is only for demo purpose showing the resulting types.  It does not effect the changes to original dataframe without reassigning to the original dataframe.  (The doc is somewhat misleading to new Pandas users!)

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   value_1  Value_2
0       10       20
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df.astype(int)



 value_1  Value_2
0       10       20
```